How to create a run flow using prefect api?
I'm trying to run a prefect flow from a deployment I've already created. The name of my deployment is my-deployment-test. Context: I basically need to create a function that receives the deployment name or deployment id as a parameter and executes a flow. I tried using the create_flow_run_from_deployment method but it only gives an error
async def run_prefect_flow(flow_name: str): try: async with get_client() as client: deployment = await client.read_deployment_by_name(flow_name) flow_run = await client.create_flow_run_from_deployment(deployment.id) return flow_run except PrefectHTTPStatusError as e: print(f"Ocorreu um erro ao tentar executar a flow {flow_name}: {e}") return None

Please [edit] your post to: complete your [mre], adding details and including error messages and debugging information; correctly format your code; add any additional relevant tags, if these exist.

I'm not sure this is enough information to help.
can you share the output of prefect version and some actual code / tracebacks that illustrate what you're trying to do and how exactly it's going wrong?
feel free to join the Slack if that'd be easier for you

Ah ok, I joined the Slack community and sent my question to the ask-community channel
